# Вызов функции базы данных из java-программы

Tags: postgresql, база-данных, sql, java, функции

Есть база данных `Postgresql` со следующей функцией-заглушкой

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION net_train(terms text[], answer integer)
  RETURNS void AS
$BODY$begin
--this code is stub
end;$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION net_train(text[], integer)
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

Необходимо вызвать эту функцию из `java` программы. Подскажите как это сделать (желательно с примером кода).

Comment: hibernate ?

Comment: @Gorets, а можно подробнее с примером вызова? (очень нужно, `java` глубоко не знаю).

Comment: ооо, ну тогда я не знаю, расскажи что тебе сделать надо подробнее

Comment: так я уже сказал, если более подробнее, то функция-заглушка будет вызваться некоторое чиcло раз в цикле `for`. Каким образом осуществить вызов этой функции в цикле (я не имею представления об операторах, позволяющих вызвать эту функцию в java-программе)?

Comment: @Gorets зачем ты предлагаешь чайнику Hibernate? Он же умрет, но не сделает - проще через обычный JDBC

Answer (score 2):

JDBC в руки и вперед. Копать в сторону `CallableStatement` - [пример индусского кода здесь](http://www.roseindia.net/tutorial/java/jdbc/jdbccallablestatement.html)

**Update** по ссылке приведен пример с MySQL для Postgres код не изменится за исключением момента подключения JDBC драйвера для Postgres: [например так](http://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/how-do-connect-to-postgresql-with-jdbc-driver-java/)